# Ruby gem Mechanize with jRuby 1.6.0 (Ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby, jruby, mechanize

When I tried to access a web site with SSL using Mechanize, I got the following error.

```
jruby-1.6.0 :009 > page = mechanize_agent.submit(form) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `read_nonblock' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket:0x44cae5b8>
```

I tried with Mechanize both 2.0.pre.2 and 1.0.0.

jRuby installed is: 
jruby 1.6.0 (ruby 1.9.2 patchlevel 136) (2011-03-15 f3b6154) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_24)

I also installed the gem jruby-openssl.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug, and there's a monkey patch you can use to get around it. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5529

Link to monkey patch at the bottom.